# Owl carousel "items" not working on 1900 + pixels

Tags: javascript, owl-carousel

I have this code. It's ok to 1899px, but big than 1900px, the items option not working.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".owl-case").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000,
        items: 3, // THIS IS IMPORTANT
        responsiveClass:true
    });
});
```

First image on 1899px:

[image: Images in 1899px]

Second image on 1900px

[image]

Thank for answers!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".owl-case").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000,
        items: 3, // THIS IS IMPORTANT
        loop: true,
        responsiveClass:true
    });
});
```

Comment: better to mention some details about the solution

Answer (score 0):

You are missing loop: true,

```
jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    $(".owl-case").owlCarousel({
        autoPlay: 3000,
        items: 3, // THIS IS IMPORTANT
        loop: true,
        responsiveClass:true
    });
});
```

As in my case it is working...

or may be it's the jquery library.

I am using jquery-2.1.4.min.js.